# Wordpress creating links in the child theme

Tags: wordpress

How to create links in the child theme files?
I have a custom template, and had a menu generated by wordpress:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu right')); ?>
</section>
```

But since I had to customize the top bar I have created my own top bar:

```
<ul class="vertical menu text-center">
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I create links to my other pages in that menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create menu links using this code:

```
<?php
    $menuArray = wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu_name');
    foreach($menuArray as $menu):
?>
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url($menu->url);?>" class="vertical menu text-center"><?php echo $menu->title;?></a>
<?php 
    endforeach;
?>
```

Hope this code works for you.